# Single file upload with FormData

Tags: javascript, form-data

I want to upload a single file with this code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
let file = this.file[0];
formData.append("file", file);
```

Normally I use this piece of code because when I upload multiple files:

```
 let formData = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
    let file = data.files[i];
    consol
    formData.append("files[" + i + "]", file);
  }
```

But with the single file upload the `formData` variable stays empty after I append the file. When I `console.log` the `file` variable it shows me this:

```
File {name: "2020_03_17 21_53 Office Lens (1).jpg", lastModified: 1587394084978, lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 20 2020 16:48:04 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 306890, …}
lastModified: 1587394084978
lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 20 2020 16:48:04 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
name: "2020_03_17 21_53 Office Lens (1).jpg"
size: 306890
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Why is this file not appended to the FormData?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a file (in form of bytes) is never shown in console.log.

 if you're able to see the `file.size` it means that the file is present in the formdata object.

To test this - try sending this formdata to the API and use httpRequest.FormData[0] to receive it - and you''ll find that your file has been sent to the api

Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score -1):

I guess in the code you need "files" instead of "file". And also you can check what are you actually referring by "this"

```
let formData = new FormData();
let file = this.files[0];
formData.append("file", file);
```

Comment: This is not an answer.